# Does data reduction work cross datastore?

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage-area-network, unity

I am the proud owner of a Unity 400F all flash SAN connected through FC. I have multiple datastores setup for my vm infrastructure and I was wondering if data reduction (what EMC calls their combined dedup and compression, and am focusing on dedup here) works across datastore, or does the dedup only happen on vms sharing the same datastore?

Also, I set this unit up with many small datastores, similar to how I did iscsi SANs on spinning disks. From what I researched back then you should have many small datastores to help spread out the load, and I believe at the time VMware recommended some where between 5-8 vms per datastore, depending on latency. Is this still the case?

Answer (score 3):

Deduplication along with compression in Dell EMC Unity is available either on block or file level. The deduplication can be configured per datastore and works on the storage resource level. Same CG ( Consistency Groups) can contain storage resources with enabled and disabled storage reduction.
Useful link  https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h16870-dell-emc-unity-data-reduction.pdf